# query execution takes takes too long

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am trying to update multiple rows of table for which i tried the following code which takes too much time to execute. And gives error `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded`
It works some time But when i try to update more than 10 rows than it gives error.

```
$id = trim(intval($_POST['id']));
$dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$cars = array();
if(isset($_POST['cars'])){
if(count($_POST['cars']) > 0 && !empty ($_POST['cars'])){    
    foreach($_POST['cars'] as $key => $array){
        $row = array();    
        $row['car'] = strval($array['car']);
        $row['black'] = isset($array['black']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
        $row['red'] = isset($array['red']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
        $cars[$key] = $row;
    }
    }
}
    try{
                $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `cars` (`mainid`,`car`,`black`,`red`,`dates`) values(:mainid,:car,:black,:red,:dates)
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    `black`= :black,
                    `red`= :red,
                    `dates`= :dates;
                                            ");
        foreach($cars as $key => $array){
                 $query->execute(array(':mainid' => $id, ':car' => $array['car'], ':black' => $array['black'], ':red' => $array['red'], ':dates' => $dates));
            }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
           echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
       }
```

`mainid` and `car` are key columns

Comment: you are specifying `on duplicate key update` -- question: is your db table already containing large number of records ?

Comment: @KenLee my db table contains not more than 100 rows. And mostly these rows are on duplicate key update.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why these queries should take so long to execute. I have the feeling that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Per @KIKOSoftware no obvious reason in that code, but on a general note, _indenting your code properly_ would make it easier to see _if_ there are issues. You have an extra `}` before your `try`. Does the timeout also happen if you do regular inserts? Have you timed your code to see where time is spent? (E.g. `echo microtime(true) - $start;` at intervals.)